# Fetch record by join and Multiple where clause MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, join, where-clause

I have following records in these two tables.

Table-A

```
       Question_No 
           1
           2
           3
           4
           5
```

Table-B

```
Roll_No  Question  Ans_Option
 1001      1         NULL // NULL means not attempted
 1001      2         D
 1001      3         NULL // NULL means not attempted
 1002      1         C
 1002      2         NULL // NULL means not attempted
```

Here "NULL" is explicitly inserted into column Ans_Option when the student skips the question.

How can I display the following result by mysql query?

```
       Questions not attempted by roll no 1001 are : 1, 3, 4, 5 
       Questions not attempted by roll no 1002 are : 2, 3, 4, 5
```

I tried with following code but not working, how can I use multiple where clause ?

```
String skipped_Question="NULL";

String selectSQL = "select a.* from Table_A a NATURAL LEFT JOIN Table_B b 
where b.Question IS NULL or b.Ans_Option=? and b.Roll_No=?";// Here I am doing wrong I think

 preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(selectSQL);

 preparedStatement.setString(1, skipped_Question);
 preparedStatement.setString(2, Roll_No);

            try{

            rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {

      Not_Attempted_Questions= rs.getString(1);

         list.add(Not_Attempted_Questions);

            }
            }
            catch(SQLException e){    }
    out.println(list);
```

Thanks a lot in Advance

Comment: That's not mysql code - please add appropriate tag. Mixing ands and ors can be confusing, try adding appropriate brackets.

Comment: *"That's not mysql code - please add appropriate tag"* Seams it is or can be @P.Salmon ,  part off MySQL's BNF JOIN syntax -> `| table_reference NATURAL [INNER | {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER]] JOIN table_factor` [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: But most likely you are right @P.Salmon the C# [SQLException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception?view=netframework-4.8) class is for SQL Server (MSSQL) only..

Comment: I am trying but not happening

Comment: Oh yes thanks for reverting back @Larnu, SQL Server (MSSQL) offcource does not support NATURAL joins, i just remembered

Comment: @Tom i think you are mixing up C# library's to connect to MySQL, i would suggest to research how to connect to MySQL from C#.. As it seams you are using the SQL Server (MSSQL) api's to connect to MySQL which does not work..

Comment: I am using java

Comment: *"I am using java "*  Well to mine "defence" Java an C# has almost the same or very comparable syntax and the same class names... Very easy to the misidentify the source code language then so i added in the Java tag aswell

Comment: *"I tried with following code but not working,"*  i assume you don't get a error? `catch(SQLException e){    }` -> `catch(SQLException e){  e.printStackTrace();  }`

Comment: @RaymondNijland its not displaying correct records

Comment: *"its not displaying correct records"* Wierd... The query should error as i believe `NATURAL JOIN` requires atleast one same column name to exists in both tables as it is basically converted to `... JOIN ... USING()`.. Your example data does not have the same column names.

Comment: should I use only left join?

Comment: @RaymondNijland please help me out.. I am getting this error if i use only left join com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;